# Why invalid syntax when I add a statement in the same cell with pip install?

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, syntax

[notebook screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1n12.png)

I don't get this. When I use pip install, it works. As soon as I add anything other than that, even if I add a character, it says invalid syntax in the first line. Like I did not even make a change in the first line, still it gets invalid just by adding a letter or statement in the same cell. How and why?

If possible, pls mention the reference or source of your answer too.

I have tried almost everything. It works like this in cmd or power shell but not in Jupyter Notebook

Comment: Please add everything as plain text, NOT images

Comment: It looks like you're trying to execute `pip install scikit-learn` as python code.

Comment: Yes but it works when it is used only once

Comment: See [this](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-pip) and [this](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-automagic).

Comment: I would be grateful if you could elaborate. I checked both of the links but couldn't get it.

Comment: I strongly recommend you to edit your post as others commented. I reluctantly answered your question because you are a new contributor.

Answer (score 0):

It is because IPython, the backend engine of Jupyter Notebook parses lines in a cell using its own syntax. See [Python vs IPython](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/python-ipython-diff.html).

In your case the `pip` was recognized as a magic command `%pip`, because the `automagic` option is on by default.

Comment: %pip¶
Run the pip package manager within the current kernel.

This is the explanation of %pip. How does it work with one library but as soon as I add another, it says invalid syntax? Also, I cannot edit the post because to get the clarity, the image is important, it won't be understood without image. Please help me

Comment: You can write inputs and outputs of Notebook cells as text. See [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Anyway why do you think the first one(Python code following a magic command) should work? Isn't it abnormal? Are you asking for the implementation detail for that? Then see [this](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/8.9.0/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py#L3238). But I don't want to explain it in detail.